# Unbind hashchange event

Tags: bind, unbind, hashchange

is it possible to unbind the hashchange event?
I am binding it like this:

```
jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                alert("ok");
            });
```

and unbinding like this:

```
jQuery(window).off('hashchange');
```

I also tried bind and unbind.
What Am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but not sure if its the case for you- changing hash was triggering the the `onhashchange` event.

The workaround was to use history api:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, document.location.pathname + '#' + hash);
```

This will change hash without triggering the onhashchange event.